# How to save results from for loop on list into a new list under "i" vector name?

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, names

I have the following code:

```
final_results <- list()

myfunc <- function(v1) {
  deparse(substitute(v1))
}

for (i in mylist) {

...calculations...


tmp_results <- as.data.frame(cbind(effcrs,weights))
colnames(tmp_results) <- c('efficiency',names(inputs),
                     names(outputs)) # header
rownames(tmp_results) <- namesDMU[,1]

#Save to list
name_in_list <- myfunc(i)
dea_results[[name_in_list]] <- tmp_results

}
```

The above code loops through a list of data frames. I would like each result yielded from the loop to be stored in a separate list under the same name as the original file obtained from `mylist` or `i`

I tried using the `deparse substitute`. when i apply it to an individual item in `mylist` it looks like this:

```
myfunc(standard_DEA$'2010-11-11')
[1] "standard_DEA$\"2010-11-11\""
```

I don't know what the issue is. At the moment it saves everything under  the name "i" and replaces all vectors so the end result is a list of 1.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are a lot of not necessary lines in your example, while the goal you have in mind is not much clear. I'd guess that you should loop over the indices and not on the element of the list. I'd try `listnames<-names(mylist)` before the loop. Then, I'd loop with `for (j in 1:length(mylist))`, set the `i<-mylist[[j]]` and then the final assignment as `dea_results[[listnames[j]]] <- tmp_results`.

Comment: What is `myList`? Is it a list of numbers? Of filenames? Of other objects? Is it a named list, as if so are those the names you want to use for the new list?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the names in the loop. After the loop, `names(dea_results) <- names_I_want`

Comment: @PierreLafortune Read the last line of the OP: "At the moment it saves everything under the name "i"". So no point in changing the names after the loop if the list is not build correctly to start with.

Comment: @nicola if the only problem is that the names  are incorrect, channing at the end will solve it. You say it isn't being built correctly, that's a separate issue being created by the user's attempt to manipulate it.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Basically the loop always says `dea_results[["i"]] <- tmp_results`, so it will eventually result of length 1 as the new element overwrites the previous one. So changing names at the end is useless.

Comment: The question isn't reproducible so we can't test what's actually going on. They could use `dea_results[[i]] <- tmp_results`. But just guessing without the data

Comment: thank you nicola. exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you want a do loop.

```
library(dplyr)

function_which_returns_dataframe = function(i) {

   ...calculations...

   tmp_results <- as.data.frame(cbind(effcrs,weights))
   colnames(tmp_results) <- c('efficiency',names(inputs),
                     names(outputs)) # header
   rownames(tmp_results) <- namesDMU[,1]
   tmp_results
}


data_frame(mylist = mylist,
           name = names(mylist)) %>%
  group_by(mylist, name) %>%
  do(function_which_returns_dataframe(.$mylist[[1]]))
```